# wcf service does not return the parent and child records of linq-to-sql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, linq-to-sql

I am writing a wcf service, using linq to sql datacontext to do database operations.

Having a customer and orders records, one method needs to return the specific customer by id like so

```
public customer Customer_Get_By_Session_Id(string session_id) {

        //check valid session_id
        //...

        //if session_id exists, get customer info
        var saved_customer = (from p in db.customers
                              where p.session_id == session_id
                              select p).FirstOrDefault();

        return saved_customer;
    }
```

However it only returns a single customer without any orders, when called from my test method.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void CustomerGetByid()
    {

        dataclassesDataContext db = new dataclassesDataContext();
        var mycust =  db.partner_svc_customers.FirstOrDefault();

        var saved_customer = svc_wcf.Customer_Get_By_Session_Id(mycust.session_id);

        //fails! saved_customer.orders.Count() == 0
        Assert.IsTrue(saved_customer.orders.Count() == 1);


    }
```

I can work around this problem by modifying my method to manually add the orders to another customer return_customer and return that object.

```
public customer Customer_Get_By_Session_Id(string session_id) {

        //check valid session_id
        //...

        //if session_id exists, get customer info
        var saved_customer = (from p in db.customers
                              where p.session_id == session_id
                              select p).FirstOrDefault();


        var orders = saved_customer.orders.ToList();

        customer return_customer = new customer();
        return_customer = saved_customer;

        foreach (order my_order in orders)
        {
            returned_customer.orders.Add(my_order);
        }
        return returned_customer;
    }
```

Now the test completes with-out an error.

My question is Why.  What is missing here?  Shouldn't the customer object be sent over with all the orders, unadulterated, just like I expect it to be?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, this is part of the lazy loading. If the data hasn't been loaded already, then it *won't* load it simply for the purpose of serialization (it uses serialization callbacks to know whether it is being serialized). If you want to *force* it, then simply iterate the orders. Actually, I suspect you'll find that simply adding this line:

```
var orders = saved_customer.orders.ToList();
```

is what makes it work, since that forces it to load the data, i.e.

```
var saved_customer = (from p in db.customers
                      where p.session_id == session_id
                      select p).FirstOrDefault();

var orders = saved_customer.orders.ToList(); // voodoo to make orders load
return saved_customer;
```

Comment: that worked! thanks.  I was also reading similar questions and tried this approach http://codeexperiment.com/post/Returning-LINQ-to-SQL-Entities-From-WCF.aspx whree you set DataLoadOptions and dlo.LoadWith<customer>(e => e.orders); before the query and it did the trick.